# Call ChartJS details in main Javascript file

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a Charts JS chart. I am able to click on the chart and show some chart info that id like to see like so:

```
onClick: (evt, activeEls, chart) => {
    
    alert(chart.data.labels[activeEls[0].index]);

},
```

My chartJS script currently lives in the html file. However, when I try and move this into my main.js it doesn’t work (i.e the function doesn’t run). I cant seem to figure out why.

The set up is like so:

**Main.JS:**

```
function show_info() { 
alert(chart.data.labels[activeEls[0].index]);
}
```

And I have changed that chartJS section in my HTML file to:.

```
onClick: (evt, activeEls, chart) => {
    show_info();
    
},
```

How can I set it so that the function lives in my Main.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the variable `chart` is unknown in the scope of `main.js`. Therefore, you would need to provide the `chart` variable to `show_info` like so:

```
// main.js
function show_info(my_object) { 

alert(my_object.data.labels[activeEls[0].index]);
}

// other file
onClick: (evt, activeEls, chart) => {
    show_info(chart);
    
},
```